# Cannot programmatically add to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I need to programmatically add UI components to an existing JPanel. I cannot make the component I add to appear.

*Notes:*

- almost all the TestUI code is generated by NetBeans (my method is at the bottom)
- I tried to set jPanel1.validate(), jPanel1prevalidate(), and pack(), based on other answers I've come across

*Main Class:*

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestUI testUI = new TestUI();
        testUI.setVisible(true);
        testUI.addAnotherPanel();
    }    
}
```

*UI Class:*

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TestUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TestUI
     */
    public TestUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    void addAnotherPanel() {
        jPanel1.add(new JLabel("Hello World."));
        jPanel1.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `GroupLayout` with `jPanel1`(When you use an IDE like NetBean's GUI generator) but you are trying to add a component(`JLabel`) inside the `addAnotherPanel()` function directly using the `jpanel1.add(component)` function. You do not need to add the component directly to the container—that is done for you implicitly by `GroupLayout` when using one of the`addComponent` methods.

However, `GroupLayout` wasn't designed to be used while layouting component using hand coded. Try learning other `LayoutManager` to layout component programatically. 
Check the [How to Use GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) for details.